# What exactly does the Select Similar > Face Regions operator do?

Tags: selection-tools

When I select a mesh in my scene and press Shift+G to Select Similar > Face Regions, it seems to select all meshes that are constructed the same. I can't seem to find any information on what this operation does exactly, other than what it appears to be doing. Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select Similar Face Regions will select all faces similar with the topology of your selection.

[image: Face Regions]

Comment: It seems that it is "similar" in the sense that the matching topological selections can be scaled differently or be in different places, but from my experience, the topology has to be "exactly" the same and contain the same amount of faces and vertices in order to be recognized as similar face regions. Would you agree with that?

Comment: I meant to say similar arrangement of faces, its not restricted to exact size of the faces.